# Android Apps to Duplicate Computer Display

Tags: android, display, tablet, wireless

I'm seeking an app that will display a copy of my Windows laptop screen on my Android tablet, through a wireless connection.  Since the goal is to monitor a finicky bot on my laptop which depends upon mouse position, etc., to prevent accidental interference with the bot, the app shouldn't allow input from the tablet to the laptop (or better yet, it could have a setting to toggle input on or off at will).  What options are available?

Requirements

- Wireless
- No tablet to laptop input (or preferably a setting)
- Free

Comment: Not tried any of them (and I live in an MS-free zone) – but you might wish to take a look at my list of [second screen](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc#group_652) and [remote desktop](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc#group_656) apps while waiting for good recommendations here.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for *windows screen to android* found a few options:

- [spacedesk](http://spacedesk.ph)

  Windows Network Display Monitor Software - 
  spacedesk expands the Windows desktop computer screen to other computers over the local area network.

  This page has a quick guide to it [Use Your Android Device as a Second Monitor for Your Windows PC](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/use-your-android-device-as-second-monitor-for-your-windows-pc-0175646/). Basically install on PC & android, connect, and your android should show up as another screen in Windows' settings.
- [Splashtop Streamer](http://www.splashtop.com/downloads)

  More like a remote desktop application, can interact with the PC. [Guidingtech.com page here](https://www.guidingtech.com/32361/stream-windows-8-android/)

The [spacedesk website](http://spacedesk.ph/features/) has a nice list of alternative software too:

> Similar applications and apps (additional Windows display screen for screen mirroring and Windows Desktop extension):
>
> - Air Display (Avatron)
> - AirParrot 2 (Squirrels)
> - Duet Display (Kairos)
> - iDisplay (Shape GmbH)
> - MaxiVista (Bartels Media)
> - Twomon USB, TwomonAir (easynlight/DevGuru)
> - XDisplay / Wired XDisplay (splashtop)
> - ZoneScreen (ZoneOS)
>
> Remote desktop applications and apps (Windows screen mirroring only / no - additional display screen / no Windows Desktop extension):
>
> - Chrome Remote Desktop
> - Microsoft Remote Desktop
> - splashtop
> - TeamViewer
> - VNC (Virtual Network Computing)